# SQL Server 2008 Foreign Key Constraint Error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a database with series of tables ddls, and in all are 13 tables. I am getting a foreign key constraint error when I run the ddl for `TBNSOR_VICTIM` table. The ddl was able to create the first fk constraint but I get an error creating the second fk constraint. Can somebody help me out or point me to what am missing in the scripts? This is the error am getting after running the ddl scripts

> *Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.TBNSOR_OFFENSE' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'RD09RD03'*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_OFFENSE](
    [RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_RD01_RC17SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RD03_RC27OFFENSE_DESC] [varchar] (100) NULL,
    [RD03_STATUTE] [char](6) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27PREDATOR_IND] [char] (1) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CONVICTION_DT] [date] NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CONVICT_CITY] [varchar] (20) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CONVICT_STATE] [char] (2) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CONVICT_COUNTY] [varchar] (20) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CITY] [varchar] (20) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27COUNTY] [varchar] (20) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27OFFENSE_STATE] [char] (2) NULL,
    [RD03_RC27OFFENSE_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [RD03_RC27CONFIN_REL_DT] [date] NULL,
    [RD03_RC27PP_RELEASE_DT] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CJ38ID03] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR] ASC,
    [FK_RD01_RC17SID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_OFFENSE]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [RD03RD01] FOREIGN KEY([FK_RD01_RC17SID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBNSOR_PHYSCSC] ([RD01_RC17SID])ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_OFFENSE]  CHECK  CONSTRAINT [RD03RD01]
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_VICTIM](
    [RD09_RC28SEQ_NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_RD01_RC17SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RD09_RC28SEX] [char] (1) NULL,
    [RD09_RC28RACE] [char] (1) NULL,
    [RD09_RC28AGE] [char](2) NULL,
    [RD09_RC28HIGH_AGE] [char] (2) NULL,
    [RD09_RC28LOW_AGE] [char] (2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [CJ38ID09] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RD09_RC28SEQ_NUM] ASC,
    [FK_RD01_RC17SID] ASC,
    [FK_RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_VICTIM] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [RD09RD01] FOREIGN KEY([FK_RD01_RC17SID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBNSOR_PHYSCSC] ([RD01_RC17SID])ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_VICTIM] CHECK  CONSTRAINT [RD09RD01]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_VICTIM] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [RD09RD03] FOREIGN KEY([FK_RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBNSOR_OFFENSE]([RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR])ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBNSOR_VICTIM] CHECK CONSTRAINT [RD09RD03]
GO
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095216/sql-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have primary key set up on two columns ([RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR] and [FK_RD01_RC17SID]) in [CJ38TBNSOR_OFFENSE] table, but your referencing just one of them.
It should be:

```
REFERENCES [cj38].[CJ38TBNSOR_OFFENSE]([RD03_RC27SEQ_NBR],[FK_RD01_RC17SID])
```

Comment: The foreign key itself should also consist of two columns instead of one.